# Modify the Wordpress HTML tags that was generated automatically

Tags: php, html, wordpress, tags

I'm creating a website with wordpress.

I created a gallery with the Media Library of the wordpress and 
I also created template page-portfolio.php all with php (wordpress) and everything works fine.

With the Inspect Element I check in the page-portfolio.php HTML code with tags which was generated automatically by wordpress.

```
<div id="gallery-1" class="gallery galleryid-11">
<div class="myGalleryItem"><a ref="..."><img src="..."></a><span>...</span></div>
<div class="myGalleryItem"><a ref="..."><img src="..."></a><span>...</span></div>
<div class="myGalleryItem"><a ref="..."><img src="..."></a><span>...</span></div>
...
```

and I want to change that HTML tags to the following code:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="box">
    <div class="boxInner">...</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="boxInner">...</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="boxInner">...</div>
...
```

the goal is to customize the HTML tags in order to adjust i.e. adptar a CSS gallery grid photos see link:http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/

How can I modify the wordpress HTML code with tags that was generated automatically ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Your question is rather vague, please elaborate. Meanwhile I think you might be looking for 'filtering the content': `<?php add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_function_name' ) ?>` Look at: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/. In addition: you might be looking to "unhook" a filter that someone else has added before you.

Comment: I want to adapt a responsive photo gallery with pure CSS like this in the http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/ but the problem is I need to change the page-portfolio.php HTML tags which was generated automatically by wordpress according to the responsive photo gallery with pure CSS. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: In the page-portfolio.php (Inspect Element ) we have the following HTML code with tags which was generated automatically by wordpress:

<div id="gallery-1" class="gallery galleryid-11">
 <div class="myGalleryItem">...</div>
 <div class="myGalleryItem">...</div>
 ...
</div>
and I want to change that HTML tags to the following code:
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="box">
  <div class="boxInner">...</div>
 <div class="box">
  <div class="boxInner">...</div>
 <div class="box">
  <div class="boxInner">...</div>
 ...
</div>